# How can I prove a a negative norm is not convex?

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove that $f(x) = -\lVert x \rVert^2$ is not convex.

I know that $f(x) = \lVert x \rVert^2$ is convex by the following proof:

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\lVert \alpha x + (1 - \alpha )y \rVert^2 & \leq \lVert \alpha x\rVert^2 + \lVert (1 - \alpha)y\rVert^2 \\
 & = \alpha^2\lVert x\rVert^2 + (1 - \alpha)^2\lVert y\rVert^2 \\ & \leq \alpha \lVert x\rVert^2 + (1 - \alpha) \lVert y\rVert^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

How do I prove that the negative version of this is not convex? Intuitively I know that it must be concave, but I don't know how I can prove.

Comment: In the zero space $-\|x\|^2$ is convex. If the space has an $x\neq0$, then you have that $\frac{(-\|x\|^2)+(-\|-x\|^2)}{2}=-\|x\|^2<0=\left\|\frac{x+(-x)}{2}\right\|$

Comment: $\lVert \alpha x\rVert^2 + \lVert (1 - \alpha)y\rVert^2  = \alpha\lVert x\rVert^2 + (1 - \alpha)\lVert y\rVert^2$? I do not think so. $\lVert \alpha x\rVert^2=\alpha^2\lVert x\rVert^2$, not $\alpha\lVert x\rVert^2$.

Comment: Why not? They are just scalars.

Answer (score 2):

To prove $f$ is not convex, all you need is to find an example where $f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) > \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y)$ with $0 \le \alpha \le 1$.  Try $\alpha = 1/2$ and $y=-x$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $||a.x+(1-a).y||^2 \leq a.||x||^2 + (1-a).||y||^2$ for $0\leq a\leq 1$. Multiplying both sides by -1, you have

$-||a.x+(1-a).y||^2 \geq a.(-||x||^2) + (1-a).(-||y||^2)$

Now, think about the equality. There are a few cases where the equality occurs. Thus, there are many counterexamples as shown in the comments.